# Bibtex Not Working in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, texstudio

I present a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\makeatletter
\let\insertsupervisor\relax
\newcommand\supervisortitle{Supervisor}
\mode<all>
{
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\def\insertsupervisor{#1}}
\titlegraphic{}
}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{supdefault}[1][]
{
\vbox{}
\vfill
\begingroup
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\relax%
    \else%
    \vskip0.25em%
    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]    
{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
    \fi%     
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\vskip1em\par
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}
\ifx\insertsupervisor\relax\relax\else
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
    \usebeamerfont{author}\supervisortitle:~\insertsupervisor
\end{beamercolorbox}\fi
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}                    
\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}

\title[main]{main document}
\author{me}
\supervisor{supervisor}

\AtBeginSection{%
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=1-2,,currentsection]
    \framebreak
    \tableofcontents[sections=3-5,,currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=white,fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{subsection number projected}{bg=white,fg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[sections=1-2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[sections=3-5]
\end{frame}

\section{References and Acknowledgements}
%\subsection{References}
\begin{frame}
test
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\subsection{Acknowledgements}
\end{document}
```

***Updated MWE (4/2/18)***
I ran this MWE and found the same error. Please advice.

Comment: You should run biber not bibtex. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: It should probably be `citestyle=authoryear` and beamer does not have a `13pt` option.

Comment: I've corrected accordingly, as adviced, but I'm told that biber.sty is not found despite the fact that I have miktex.biber.bin installed and updated.

Comment: Where do you get a message about `biber.sty`? No such file exists, if you edit your document to incorporate samcarter's suggestion things should work fine and not search for `biber.sty`. Now the `Error: Command crashed` is more interesting. Double-check your settings with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/. Can you try to run `biber document` (assuming your `.tex` file is called `document.tex`) from the command line and check the output? Is there are `.blg` file? What does it say?

Comment: @moewe it seems I previously misunderstood the message for biber. In anycase, I've double checked the settings and followed the instructions to run PdfLatex, Biber, then the error hits me.

Assuming I'm right about how to run the command from the terminal, type: `biber document`  , no `.blg` file was found.

Comment: But when you type `biber document` in the terminal what is the message?

Comment: Am I doing it wrong.. cause I didn't get any message following that some how. On the TexStudio log it's shown:
`No file main.bbl.
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) main(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.`

Comment: Do you really run `biber document` from the command line, or do you run it from your editor? If you run it from the command line you will see diagnostic output. Please show that output. The output you get from your editor might be filtered an incomplete. Please show the unfiltered output. What you showed in your last comment are LaTeX's warnings, not Biber's warnings.

Comment: @moewe From TexStudio, I go to Tools, Open Terminal and type in `biber main` right? That's what I did. Sorry I'm really not too familiar with this.

Comment: What OS do you use? Windows, Linux or Mac OS X? Please open the terminal from your OS navigate to the folder containing your `.tex` file, using the `cd` command. And then type in `biber main`.

Comment: I use Windows. So it seems some how that `The code execution cannot proceed because cygwin1.dll was not found`. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: OK. Press Windows+R. Somewhere on your screen a small box should appear type in `cmd` and press enter. A command line window should appear. In that window use `cd` to navigate to the folder where your `.tex` file resides. Once you are inside that folder with your command line execute `biber document`. For help on the command line, see https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands, https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/

Comment: I did that and encountered the `cygwin.dll was not found` error. and another .dll error. It seems I've managed to rectify the problem by installing cygwin and copying the files to where Biber.exe resides. Now I get this `/biber: error while loading shared libraries: cygperl5_22.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` on my cmd.

Comment: Mhhh, that sounds like you got the Cygwin binary of Biber instead of your TeX live/MikTeX version. Do you use TeX live or MikTeX? What does the command line respond if you type `where biber`?

Comment: I use MikTex. where biber gives: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\biber.exe` Do you mean I should possibly reinstall MikTex? What I did to rectify the cygwin.dll not found error was to install Cygwin and the copying the missing files over.  Was that the right move?

I'm attempting to update MikTex to see what happens.

Comment: Mhhh. AFAIK MikTeX's Biber does not need Cygwin, so it should not complain about it. I don't think I have any Cygwin on my machine and the Biber installed by MikTeX works just fine for me. If you installed Biber manually that could explain the problem if you installed the Cygwin Biber binary instead of the 'normal'  Windows binary. But if you used MikTeX's package manager you should get the correct version. Of course you can try to update and to remove Biber and reinstall using the package Manager.

Comment: After updating MikTex, that seemed to have sorted out the problem. bbl file was created. So, following the pdfLatex, then biber, then pdfLatex procedure.. On the second pdfLatex run, it suggested that I have an `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`.

Comment: Ha! There will be a line just above that error message, what does it say?

Comment: ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
(C:\Users\clare\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\esint\uesint.fd)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd") (main.bbl)
(main.nav) [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./crest.png>
] (main.toc) [2] (main.toc) [3] (main.toc) (main.toc) [4] [5] [6] [7]
<wip.png, id=253, 488.82625pt x 438.63875pt> <use wip.png> [8 <./wip.png>]
[9] [10] (main.toc) (main.toc) [11] [12] (main.toc) (main.toc)

Comment: I managed to find the error.. seems to have been the line:
`\AtBeginSection{%
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=1-2,,currentsection]
    \framebreak
    \tableofcontents[sections=3-5,,currentsection]
\end{frame}
}`

After changing it to
`\AtBeginSection[]{%`, it was able to compile. Thanks lots @moewe

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the error.. seems to have been the line:

```
\AtBeginSection{%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] \frametitle{Outline} 
\tableofcontents[sections=1-2,,currentsection]
\framebreak 
\tableofcontents[sections=3-5,,currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
```

After changing it to

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
```

it was able to compile.

Many thanks to @moewe, I guess the problem was partly with updating MikTex and then with this. I'm not sure why the missing `[]` became an issue given that I copied the para from elsewhere though.

Comment: Well `\AtBeginSection` is executed whenever you start a new `\section`. `\printbibliography` starts a new (starred) section (`\section*`) as well. But since `\printbibliography` is called from within a frame you produce a frame in a frame. That is just wrong.

Comment: I see.. so the `[]` rectifies that?

Comment: If you add `[]` the `\AtBeginSection` does nothing for the starred `\section*` command which `\printbibliography` uses.